# Sort Laravel collection where object is greater than 0 - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, json, laravel, collections, laravel-5

I'am making calls to the Halo 5 API, particularly, getting weapons used by each player in Arena. The problem I'am having is when I make that call, there are 7 weapons that have 0 kills by a player, like this:

```
18 => array:3 [▼
    "WeaponId" => 2457457776.0
    "TotalKills" => 0
    "TotalHeadshots" => 0
  ]
  53 => array:3 [▼
    "WeaponId" => 2015271382
    "TotalKills" => 0
    "TotalHeadshots" => 0
  ]
  51 => array:3 [▶]
  48 => array:3 [▶]
  44 => array:3 [▶]
  27 => array:3 [▶]
  32 => array:3 [▶]
```

I want to take those 7 weapons out of my collection:

This is how my collection is set up:

```
    public function getArenaWeaponKills($playerArenaWeaponStats) {

        $results = collect($playerArenaWeaponStats->Results[0]->Result->ArenaStats->WeaponStats);

        $array = $results->sortByDesc('TotalKills')->map(function($item, $key) {
            return [
                'WeaponId' => $item->WeaponId->StockId,
                'TotalKills'   => $item->TotalKills,
                'TotalHeadshots' => $item->TotalHeadshots,
            ];
        });

        return $array;
    }
```

Right now I'am sorting them by ('TotalKills') descending order. Is there a way to sort them the same way Including checking if 'TotalKills' is > then 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add a filter() method to the chain:

```
$array = $results->sortByDesc('TotalKills')
        ->filter(function ($item) {
            return $item->TotalKills > 0;
        })
        ->map(function($item, $key) {
            return [
                'WeaponId' => $item->WeaponId->StockId,
                'TotalKills'   => $item->TotalKills,
                'TotalHeadshots' => $item->TotalHeadshots,
            ];
        });
```

Comment: very nice solution